# Ошибка взаимодействия кнопок discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

Я хочу сделать отслеживание нажатия кнопок в *discord.py*, то есть сделать так, что бы при нажатии на одну кнопку бот отправлял одно сообщение, при нажатии на другую кнопку - отправлял другое сообщение.

Я ожидал, что бот будет отправлять различные сообщения в зависимости от нажатой кнопки, а получилось так, что сообщения не отправились, и в Дискорде после нажатия на одну из кнопок под сообщением появлялась надпись **"Ошибка взаимодействия"**. В консоли Python никаких ошибок нет.

Пробовал делать отслеживание через *@bot.event()*, через *responce.component.id* - ничего не помогло.

Через *@bot.event()*:

```
from discord.ext import commands
from config import settings
import discord
import discord.ui
import keep_alive

client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.default())
intents = discord.Intents.all()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=settings['prefix'], intents=intents)
bot.remove_command('help')

@bot.event
async def on_button_click(ctx):
  button_id = ctx.custom_id
  if button_id == '1':
    await ctx.send('вы нажали на кнопку 1')
  elif button_id == '2':
    await ctx.send('вы нажали на кнопку 2')

@bot.command()
async def test(ctx, *arg):
  button1 = discord.ui.Button(label="1", style=discord.ButtonStyle.gray, custom_id="1")
  button2 = discord.ui.Button(label="2", style=discord.ButtonStyle.gray, custom_id="2")
  msg = "нажмите на одну из кнопок!"
  view = discord.ui.View()
  view.add_item(button1)
  view.add_item(button2)
  await ctx.send(msg, view=view)
  await bot.wait_for('button_click')
```

Через *responce.component.id*:

```
from discord.ext import commands
from config import settings
import discord
import discord.ui
import keep_alive

client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.default())
intents = discord.Intents.all()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=settings['prefix'], intents=intents)
bot.remove_command('help')

@bot.command()
async def test(ctx, *arg):
  button1 = discord.ui.Button(label="1", style=discord.ButtonStyle.gray, custom_id="1")
  button2 = discord.ui.Button(label="2", style=discord.ButtonStyle.gray, custom_id="2")
  msg = "нажмите на одну из кнопок!"
  view = discord.ui.View()
  view.add_item(button1)
  view.add_item(button2)
  await ctx.send(msg, view=view)
  responce = await bot.wait_for('button_click')
  button_id = ctx.custom_id
  if responce.component.id == '1':
    await ctx.send('вы нажали на кнопку 1')
  elif responce.component.id == '2':
    await ctx.send('вы нажали на кнопку 2')

keep_alive.keep_alive()
bot.run(settings['token'])
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно сделать то, что мне нужно?

Comment: Посмотрите [**этот пример**](https://github.com/denisnumb/discord-py-guide/blob/main/ui_elements.md#%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BA%D1%83)